# How do I compute the length of this module?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $A = k[x,y,z,w]$, $\mathfrak p = (x, w)$, $\mathfrak a = (x^d, w)$, for some $d \in \mathbb N$.

1. How do I compute $(A/\mathfrak a)_\mathfrak p$?
2. How do I compute the length of $(A/\mathfrak a)_\mathfrak p$ as an $A_\mathfrak p$-module?

**EDIT:** Is the following procedure correct?

My basic idea is to use the exact sequence

$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathfrak p/\mathfrak a
  \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak a
  \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak p
  \longrightarrow 0,
$$

and localize it at $\mathfrak p$. Since $w = 0$ in all three quotients, we may replace $A, \mathfrak p, \mathfrak a$ as follows:

$$
A = k[x,y,z], \qquad \qquad
\mathfrak p = (x), \qquad \qquad
\mathfrak a = (x^d) = \mathfrak p^d.
$$

Then the aforementioned exact sequence becomes

$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^d
  \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak p^d
  \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak p
  \longrightarrow 0.
$$

Since $A$ is an integral domain and $\mathfrak p = xA$ is a nonzero principal ideal, the $A$-homomorphism $\varphi : A \to \mathfrak p$ defined by $\varphi(f) = xf$ is an isomorphism. Then $\mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^d$ is isomorphic to $A/\mathfrak p^{d-1}$.

After localizing at $\mathfrak p$, the exact sequence becomes

$$
0 \longrightarrow (\mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^n)_\mathfrak p
  \longrightarrow (A/\mathfrak p^n)_\mathfrak p
  \longrightarrow (A/\mathfrak p)_\mathfrak p
  \longrightarrow 0.
$$

Inductively, $(\mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^d)_\mathfrak p \cong (A/\mathfrak p^{d-1})_\mathfrak p$ has length $d-1$. Since $(A/\mathfrak p)_\mathfrak p$ is the residue field of $A_\mathfrak p$, it has length $1$. Therefore, $(A/\mathfrak p^d)_\mathfrak p$ has length $(d-1) + 1 = d$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. And one can get rid of "algebraically closed".